# Do I need to migrate core data if i have only changes the type of a field: iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, ios10

I have just changed the type of one field - user_id from Integer 16 to Integer 64 do I need to migrate code data. I am developing app for iOS 10 and above. Does it can cause crash in production because it's not crash my app right now in development.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Definitely because the old user of the application will have different schema.. So the application might crash if Integer 16 fails to satisfy the Integer 64  value..

Comment: How to migrate in case of iOS 10: NSPersistentContainer? @Nilesh

Comment: You have to use Core Data version..   Follow this blog..  https://cocoacasts.com/migrating-a-data-model-with-core-data/

Comment: This is the case for the old version of core data: I have NSPersistenContainer from iOS 10. What should i do in case of NSPersistenContainer.